# pandas calculate total of previous consecutive rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
data = {'process': ['buying','selling','searhicng','repairing', 'preparing', 'selling','buying', 'searching', 'selling','searching'],
        'type': ['in_progress','in_progress','end','in_progress', 'in_progress', 'end','in_progress', 'end', 'in_progress','end'],
'country': ['usa','usa', 'usa','ghana', 'ghana','ghana','ghana', 'ghana', 'albania','albania'],
'id': ['022','022','022', '011','011', '011','011', '011', '6','6'],
'duration': [1,1,4,1,2,1,2,3,4,1]       
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['process','type','country', 'id', 'duration'])
```

[image]

I need to calculate total of duration for rows where `type=in_progress` and going up to value `type=end` and create new column `process_line` which contains list of values from `process` column

Can anyone help me

Output dataframe:

[image]

I tried to numerate every row and then selecting rows with `type=in_progress` calculate total of duration and crating list of process, but it works very slowly

```
from tqdm import  tqdm
k = 0
temp=pd.DataFrame()
res = pd.DataFrame()
for i in tqdm(list(df.drop_duplicates('id').id)):
    k=0
    temp = df[df.id==i]
    for index, row in temp.iterrows():
        if row.type=='end':
            number = pd.DataFrame([row])
            number['nn'] = k
            res = pd.concat([res,number])
            k+=1
        else:
            number = pd.DataFrame([row])
            number['nn'] = k
            res = pd.concat([res,number])
```

Comment: What have you tried. What are your ideas?

Comment: Thank you for question, i've just added it in the ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with help @fsimonjetz i understood how i can do it

```
 df['nn'] = df['type'].shift(1).eq('end').cumsum()
in_progress_df = df[df.type=='in_progress'].reset_index()
end_df = df[df.type=='end'].reset_index()



in_progress_grouped = in_progress_df.groupby('nn').agg({'process':list,
                               'type':'last',
                               'country':'first',
                               'id':'first',
                               'duration':sum,
                               'nn':'first'})\
                        .rename(columns={'nn':'number'})

res = pd.merge(in_progress_df,end_df , left_on='nn', right_on='nn').drop(labels=['type_x','country_x','id_x','duration_y','index','nn'],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```py
df['type_groups'] = df['type'].shift(1).eq('end').cumsum()
df2 = df[df['type'] != 'end'].groupby('type_groups').agg({'process': list, 
                                                          'country': 'first', 
                                                          'id': 'first', 
                                                          'duration': sum})
```

###### Result

| type_groups | process | country | id | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ['buying', 'selling'] | usa | 022 | 2 |
| 1 | ['repairing', 'preparing'] | ghana | 011 | 3 |
| 2 | ['buying'] | ghana | 011 | 2 |
| 3 | ['selling'] | albania | 6 | 4 |

Comment: It looks like columns with 'searhicng' should not be considered for the duration calculation.

Comment: It's similar to my result, but we have not consider rows with type=end in calculating and creating list of process

Comment: What is the wanted behavior. Should only rows be considered that have ended? If end is missing, what result do you aim for? Could you post the desired table with a couple of edge cases?

Comment: If you need to exclude the 'end' rows, we can filter them out before grouping (see my updated answer). But seems like you figured it out on your own!